# IOS Twilio IP Messaging initial integration steps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, twilio

I have been exploring **twilio** for 2 days and I have been unable to see some important points on their documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/identity, which is required to integrate twilio ip messaging in iOS.

What pod name is required to install **twilio** ip messaging service on iOS?
What are the other iOS in-built frameworks libraries requires to integrate for twilio?
or what are the other initial steps requires to startup with twilio ip messaging service in iOS?

I prefer the answer of this question will help me and many others in initial integration of twilio ip messaging service in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Badal. Ya it's really helpfull, so I up vote it. just forgot to make it right. still I need to go through the process, have you worked on ip messaging before?

Comment: not much more but what happen ?

Comment: Okay. I'm about to start it. if I gets stuck any thing related it,  I will comment here, hope to you will help me if you know about it.

Comment: Please up vote the question so it makes viral a bit gradually, so other also can know all initial steps of start ip messaging.

Comment: I will help you if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks Badal. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As i cover your  questions :

**1) what pod name is required to install twilio ip messaging service on ios?**

**Ans:-**  As said in twillio official documents in [This](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/sdks) link,

-For **IP Messaging Client** you need to download it from below link.

[Download the IP Messaging Client framework](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/rtc/ios/ip-messaging/v0.13/twilio-rtc-ip-messaging.tar.bz2)

-And you need some **common framework** to startup with twilio

[Download the Twilio Common framework](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/common/v0.2/twilio-common-ios.tar.bz2)

**Dont forget** to include **libstdc++.tbd** in **Linkedframeworks and Library** section.

> [image]

If you want to Download through cocoapods then, (use cocoapods preferable by me)
for whole SDK [Twilio sdk](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios) or as per your question

> ```
> 1) pod 'TwilioIPMessagingClient', :podspec => 'https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/rtc/ios/ip-messaging/v0.13/TwilioIPMessagingClient.podspec'
> 2) pod 'TwilioCommon', :podspec => 'https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/common/v0.2/TwilioCommon.podspec'
> ```

Note:- Currently i have provided download link but please download framework from [twilio sdk](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/sdks) link for updated version

**2) what are the other ios in-built frameworks libraries requires to integrate for twilio?**

**Ans:-**  Twilio has provided all the framework which needed to impliment it. and regarding some inbuilt library , integrate default helpful libraries like , AVFoundation , Audio toolbox etc. They have already provide image in their blog.

[image]

**3) what are the other initial steps requires to startup with twilio ip messaging service in ios?**

**Ans:-**  For initial startup and **.plist** entry please follow [installing-twilio-client-for-ios-using-cocoapods](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/installing-twilio-client-for-ios-using-cocoapods-2.html)

My suggestion is install it through cocoapods , it is good for dependency. so, you will not get **headersearchpath** related error or **headerfile** missing error etc.

and last but not the least,

Now you can start with importing file in your project as said in [www.twilio.com](https://www.twilio.com/).

Note:- In below link they have describe all the detail regarding which file you want to import or etc.

On the left side,

> 1) [Server Setup](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/setup)
>
> 2) [make-outgoing-call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/make-outgoing-call)
>
> 3) [hang-up-call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/hang-up-call)
>
> 4) [Connect /twilio-application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/twilio-application)
>
> 5) [passing-parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/passing-parameters)
>
> 6) [Receiving Incoming calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/incoming-connections)
>
> 7) [Making Calls in/out of your App](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/incoming-outgoing)

I hope this information is enough for you to startup with twilio.

Answer (score 1):

They forget the key element in the guidelines... in your bridging header add...

```
#import <TwilioIPMessagingClient/TwilioIPMessagingClient.h>
```